# What's the difference between upcoming PHP8's spread operator and its pre-existing compact function?

Tags: php, php-8

What's the difference between upcoming PHP8's spread operator and its pre-existing [`compact()`](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments#named-arguments-in-depth) function ?

`$data = new CustomerData(...$input);`

Comment: `explode` is used for a string do you mean `compact`?

Comment: Yes, I mixed up - compact. I've edited my Q.

Comment: What do you mean the upcoming PHP 8 spread operator? We have spread operator since PHP 5.

Comment: What https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array and https://www.php.net/compact don't explain?

Comment: @Dharman in the wiki it stats that the the spead array operator has been implemented since 7.4 https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array

Comment: @Adam That's for arrays, but we had spread operator since PHP 5.6. Since PHP 7.4 you can also use it in arrays now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Differences between Compact and Spread Operator

**Compact PHP function**:

> compact — Create array containing variables and their values

```php
<?php
$city  = "San Francisco";
$state = "CA";
$event = "SIGGRAPH";

$location_vars = array("city", "state");

$result = compact("event", $location_vars);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Which output:

```php
Array
(
    [event] => SIGGRAPH
    [city] => San Francisco
    [state] => CA
)
```

**Array spreading:**

while array spreading merge two or more array without adding a key to his value (associative array):

```php
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
$arr2 = [...$arr1]; //[1, 2, 3]
$arr3 = [0, ...$arr1]; //[0, 1, 2, 3]
$arr4 = array(...$arr1, ...$arr2, 111); //[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 111]
$arr5 = [...$arr1, ...$arr1]; //[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Also array spreading can be used to fill arguments of a method call, assume that you have this constructor to your class:

```php
class CustomerData
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $name,
        public string $email,
        public int $age,
    ) {}
}
```

And use the **array spreading** to create the `CustomerData` object:

```php
$input = [
    'age' => 25,
    'name' => 'Brent',
    'email' => 'brent@stitcher.io',
];

$data = new CustomerData(...$input);
```

Which as the same behavior as:

```php
$input = [
    'age' => 25,
    'name' => 'Brent',
    'email' => 'brent@stitcher.io',
];

$data = new CustomerData($input['age'], $input['name'], $input['email']);
```

> PHP has already supported argument unpacking (AKA spread operator) since 5.6. This RFC proposes to bring this feature to array expression.

Also spread operator in array expression is implemented since PHP 7.4.

**Sources:**

[PHP: compact - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

[PHP: Spread Operator in Array Expression](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array)

### Upcomming PHP 8: named arguments

From: [PHP 8: named arguments](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params)

> Named arguments allow passing arguments to a function based on the parameter name, rather than the parameter position. This makes the meaning of the argument self-documenting, makes the arguments order-independent, and allows skipping default values arbitrarily

```php
class CustomerData
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $name,
        public string $email,
        public int $age,
    ) {}
}

$data = new CustomerData(
    name: $input['name'],
    email: $input['email'],
    age: $input['age'],
);
```